# Series dictionary with Cumulative result of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following dataframe where I am trying to create new column C such that it is based on cumlative value of Column 'A' and 'B' as dictionary. And also, if '0' in Column 'B', the entry of that key is deleted from 'C'

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,2,3,2],
            'B':['Hi','Hello','HiWorld','HelloWorld','0','0']})

for indx,row in df.iterrows():
    df['C'].append(dict(zip([row['A'],row['B']])))
```

I am looking for the following output in column C:

```
   A              B             C
0  1             Hi            {1:Hi}
1  2          Hello            {1:Hi,2:Hello}
2  3        HiWorld            {1:Hi,2:Hello,3:HiWorld}
3  2     HelloWorld            {1:Hi,2:HelloWorld,3:HiWorld}
4  3              0            {1:Hi,2:HelloWorld}
5  2              0            {1:Hi}
```

I have tried potential solutions using cumsum, concat & series.shift(1) but had a block. Now I came across using dict & zip which seems clean solution but doesn't work for me. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = dict()
column = list()
for _, a, b in df.itertuples():
    if b != '0':
        d[a] = b
    else:
        d.pop(a, None)
    column.append(d.copy())

df['C'] = column
```

Comment: Thanks @elyase this worked for me. I used OrderedDict() instead of dict() to maintain the order. I still need to collect some reputations to up your comment.